# Is it possible to copy a website with its plugin?

Tags: copy, web, cracking

Is it possible to copy a website with its plugin? There's a site which I want to have. However, it's really too expensive to buy. As I said, is there a way to copy that website with its plugin?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible. if it is WordPress website then copy everything and paste into server and change the Database setting in wp-config.php and also change the site url and home url in wp-option table.